# Get date from int (YYYYMMDD)

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, date, datetime

By doing a mistake a few months ago I got myself in a situation, where I have to find a workaround for the following problem:

I am saving dates as integer in a common format inside my SQL Server database (YYYYMMDD). I want to have my select statement giving me the integer in a format, that looks like a date (or even is in a true date type) to the user, so I can use the received datatable directly as datasource for my DataGridView.

- I do not want to use clientside formatting
- Let's call the table `myTable` and the integer/date column `myIntDate`
- `myIntDate` can be `NULL`
- sample `myIntDate-value` : 20160803 for the 3rd of August 2016

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Many of the dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to put that in! I'm Using TSQL (Microsoft) @dfundako I have, but it's kinda hard for me to find good keywords for the search.

Comment: I Google `sql server convert int to date yyyymmdd` and the top result was a correct answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Select cast(cast(20160729 as varchar(10)) as date)
```

**Returns**

```
2016-07-29
```

**Or**

```
 Select cast(left(20160729,8) as date)
```

Comment: no need to cast it as `VARCHAR(10)`, `VARCHAR(8)` will do

Comment: That seems quite easy. I'm done with coding if you're right! Gonna see how it handles NULL Values

Comment: @luke it will just return a NULL value. If the input is null. If you need a default date instead of null wrap it in an isnull.

Comment: @luke  a null value will return a null date

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @Lamak Agreed.  This was a muscle-memory thing.  I tend to define varchars with nice round numbers 5,10,25,50,..

Comment: @Luke "done with coding"   Don't be silly.  I learn little tricks every day.  That's the fun part.  cheers.

Comment: Why do I have to cast it as varchar first? Offtopic:  @JohnCappelletti Well sometimes i feel quite dumb asking questions when the solution is that easy. Of course I won't quite coding since it's my job for a year by now :-)

Comment: @Luke  the cast as date requires a string otherwise you will get an Explicit conversion error.  SQL was smart enough to allow multiple string formats into a date  ie, '7/29/2016' or '2016-07-29'